# Is this correct: std::views::reverse on infinite range?

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, c++20, std-ranges

See this example [code](https://godbolt.org/z/3ddKEc6Mv):

```
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    for(auto i : std::ranges::iota_view(1) | std::views::reverse) 
        break;
}
```

It compiles on gcc (I cannot check on clang/msvc - since they do not support ranges).
Of course -- it runs "forever" and does nothing.

I also checked that doing `std::ranges::rbegin(inf)` or `std::ranges::rend(inf)` on infinite range is not allowed (it does not compile).

I am not sure if this is correct c++ code?
And I am curious about std::ranges::reverse implementation - looks like rbegin/rend is not used to  implement this view -- so how this implementation works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [[iterator.requirements.general-10]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterators#iterator.requirements.general-10):

> A sentinel `s` is called *reachable from* an iterator `i` if and only if
> there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression `++i` that
> makes `i == s`. If `s` is reachable from `i`, [`i`, `s`) denotes a *valid range*.

And [[iterator.requirements.general-12]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterators#iterator.requirements.general-12):

> The result of the application of library functions to invalid ranges
> is undefined.

Since `ranges::iota_view(1)` is not a *valid range*, applying `views::reverse` to it is undefined behavior.

Comment: So, not all ranges in std library are valid per definition. Interesting idea. From deleted @Artyer answer I read that `ranges::next(ranges::begin(base_), ranges::end(base_)) ` is used to implement reverse for ranges with sentinel end iterator. The question: could the c++ std be improved by requiring that "application of library functions to invalid ranges" is not allowed (i.e. will not compile) instead of just say "undefined"?

Comment: @PiotrNycz. That is an improvement. But the current standard does *not* have so-called "infinite range" (only range-v3 has), because it is very different from the "traditional" container and is not suitable for standard algorithms, so the introduction of the concept of "infinite range" requires a paper, which is also why the current standard only defines it as undefined behavior.